# Angular2: ngFor iterating through object array

Tags: angular

For example with this JSON:

```
{
  "TableRows": [
    {
      "Name": "Lord of the Rnis",
      "Length": "2:40"
    }
  ],
  "Category": "Fantasy"
}
```

Into these classes:

```
export interface IMovies{
    Category: string;
    TableRows: ITableRows[];
}

export interface ITableRows{
    Name: string;
    Length: string;
}
```

The following ngFor logic works great, but it's not what I want to loop:

```
<tr *ngFor="let row of rows">
    <td>{{row.Category}}</td>
    <td>{{row.TableRows[0].Name}}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

This logic does NOT work:

```
<tr *ngFor="let row of rows.TableRows">
     <td>{{row.Name}}</td>
     <td>{{row.Length}}<td>
</tr>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: what are rows? an array or Imovies? or an array of ITableRows??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, your first statement will not be working.

> The first statement

```
<tr *ngFor="let row of rows">
    <td>{{row.Category}}</td>
    <td>{{row.TableRows[0].Name}}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

This is not working because `ngFor` in `angular 2` is similar to that of `ng-repeat` in `angular 1`. In order for your `ngFor` to work, the looping item must be an array, in your case rows is an object and not an array so clearly it won't work.

> In your second statement

```
<tr *ngFor="let row of rows.TableRows">
     <td>{{row.Name}}</td>
     <td>{{row.Length}}<td>
</tr>
```

The looping item `rows.TableRows` is an array with one element, so that will work and will produce the output as

```
Lord of the Rnis    2:40
```

I hope this is what you are looking for.